# Save XML file with only client-side action

Tags: javascript, xml, save

at work I'm trying to write a small Web-Application to more easily modify existing XML-Files, which we use internally. The XML-Files are stored in our network and are accessible through the filesystem.

Saving the data is the problem. Now I know via PHP this would be simple, but since can't get any server access, I'm limited to the client-side.

As far as I understand it, JS won't get the ability to interact with the FS any time soon. So I figured, it would probably be the easiest solution to just print out the data to a new window and use the browsers SAVE AS function to save the XML files (which would be perfectly acceptable). But:

since it's still the same document, whenever I save it, I get the entire source code and not only the specific window.

Does anyone have any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You could open new window and set its content to the XML file. Since there are problems setting XML content to window, you will have to use `<textarea/>` HTML tag with XML file string as its content. Here's a minimal example:

```
var wnd = window.open();
wnd.document.open();
wnd.document.write(
    '<textarea>' +
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
    '<note>' +
        '<to>You</to>' +
        '<from>Me</from>' +
    '</note>' +
    '</textarea>'
);
wnd.document.close();
```

You can find jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc33H/%20here)